# Configuring Apache2 (latest) for Localhost Only Ubuntu 20.04lts desktop

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, lamp

I need some help configuring Apache2 to work on my Ubuntu 20.04lts pc. I am a beginner working with Ubuntu and setting up a server so I kind of need things explained for a novice.

The purpose is to have a sandbox install of Magento 2.4.2 so I can learn how to run a store on it. First I have to install a LAMP in Ubuntu.

The first time I had installed Apache2 I was able to see the Apache2 page in my web browser but due to technical issues I had to completely re-format and install Ubuntu.

On my new instance of Ubuntu after I installed Apache2 I saw it was running but no web browser page just the Forbidden Access warning.

How do I configure Apache2 for localhost and what other configurations do I need to setup.

Apache2 is now broken when I try and see it’s status.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: When you say "Apache2 is now broken", I'm going to assume that you've made some changes to the configuration files. Could you outline the steps you've followed so far? By knowing what's been done it will be much easier to provide specific solutions 

Comment: The error was in line 228. The IP address. I tried 127.0.0.1, and 127.0.1.1 as was suggested. At the end of the file I put ServerName localhost. The error kept coming back that the syntax was wrong for line 228. I made no other changes.  I removed the ServerName localhost and tried changing the IP address on line 228.Thank you

Comment: Line 228 of which file? `apache2.conf`? If so, you needn't touch anything in that file. All of the settings you'll need to work with will be in site-specific `.conf` files located in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`. Change the last line of `apache2.conf` back to `ServerName 127.0.0.1`, as that's the local host address.

Comment: OK I will give it a try. The file I modified at line 228 just had 4 .s with no IP address. So I thought I was in the right place. The computer is at work so I will make the changes tomorrow. Thank you

Comment: I have made that change and I am getting -  A start job for unit apache2.service has finished with a failure.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 3350 and the job result is failed.
Feb 26 11:05:20 HyperMillhem sudo[6250]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Feb 26 11:05:29 HyperMillhem systemd[1]: systemd-hostnamed.service: Succeeded.
-- Subject: Unit succeeded
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- The unit systemd-hostnamed.service has successfully entered the 'dead' state. Apache2 fails to launch.

Comment: In the apache2.conf file line 228 has no IP Address and the last line is SeverName 127.0.0.1 and Apache2 fails to load. Unsure of what to do. Should I uninstall Apache2 and start again? Thank you

Comment: It seems that at the location for the suntax error is /etc/apache2/apache which does not exist as a file in the etc directory. AH00526: Syntax error on line 228 of /etc/apache2/apache Could it be that I am missing a .conf file in this location?

Comment: # vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
# ....   THIS is where my error code is pointing
# Include the virtual host configurations:
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf
ServerName 127.0.0.1

Comment: [Fri Feb 26 11:53:35.074030 2021] [core:warn] [pid 7496] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_DIR} is not defined
apache2: Syntax error on line 80 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: DefaultRuntimeDir must be a valid directory, absolute or relative to ServerRoot This is another error I am getting.